# Using letsencrypt to sign SSL certificates for local servers

Tags: ssl, certificate, lets-encrypt

Can I use a certificate from letsencrypt to sign local certificates?

I'm annoyed when accessing routers and APs at `192.168.x.x` to get security warnings.

I could create my own root cert, and import it into all my browsers etc, and create certs for all the local servers.

But I'd rather have the chain device -> `www.example.com` -> letsencrypt -> root

Then also guests could use my local servers/services without this security error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can not because the certificate issued to you by letsencrypt will not have the keyusage `certificate signing` enabled. Without this attribute in the issuer, any browser or SSL client musth reject the certificate.

If this were possible, anyone could issue valid certificates for any server simply by having a valid certificate from a trusted CA

If you want to issue certificates for your local servers you will need to create your own CA and include the root certificate in the truststore of each client

Comment: Also the Basic Constraints extension must assert the CA boolean.

Answer (score 0):

## Yes, you can... but not like that

**Yes**, you can get certificates for servers on a private network. The domain must be a real domain with **public txt records**, but the A, AAAA, and CNAME records can be private/non-routable (or in a private zone).

**No**, the way to do that isn't by using Let's Encrypt certificates to sign local certificates.

You can accomplish exactly what you want to accomplish using the DNS-01 challenge (setting txt records for your domain).

Who is your domain / dns provider?

## Immediate, but Temporary Solution

If you want to test it out real quick, try https://greenlock.domains and choose **DNS** instead of HTTP for the "how do you want to do this" step.

## Automatable Integration

If you want a configurable, automatable, deployable solution try [greenlock.js](https://git.coolaj86.com/coolaj86/greenlock-express.js) (there are node plugins for Cloudflare, Route 53, Digital Ocean, and a few other DNS providers).

Both use Let's Encrypt under the hood. Certbot can also be used for either case and can use python plugins.

## Possibly related...

P.S. You might also be interested in a service like [Telebit](https://telebit.cloud), localtunnel, or ngrok.

Comment: This does not work when the servers does not have a public domain name. I tried with "nas.home.lan"

Comment: @LeifNeland It absolutely does work for private domains on private networks, but the domain still has to be a real domain.

Comment: If you're going to downvote, at least leave some sort of constructive feedback. This both gives an accurate answer and provides alternate solutions.